# Django uwsgi using css file http1.1 404

Tags: python, css, django, http-status-code-404, uwsgi

I just put my Django application online using uwsgi. I can access it from any computer it working well.. the only thing is uwsgi can't load the css file stored in the /static/myapp/style.css path and I don't why.
The message I get when accessing a page on my site in the uwsgi console is :

```
GET /static/myapp/style.css => generated 98 bytes in 1msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 3 header in 100bytes
```

But the file is actually in /static/myapp/style.css I can see it and it was working well in developpement, but now the website is in production it's not working anymore.

I added these to my settings.py but nothing changed :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' #Was enough in developpement
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = ("/home/user/Django/mysite/static"),
```

I also tried to add option in my uwsgi command like

```
--check-static /home/user/Django/mysite/static
```

Still not working...

I'm quite new to putting online a Django app so maybe it's not supposed to work like that.
My css file is on the same machine as my Django project.
I'm using django 1.11 and uwsgi 2.5.15.

I also tried to used nginx but I couldn't get it work properly and as I just want to access my app online I concluded that uwsgi alone is enough ( Am I wrong ? )

So if you have any idea that would be great !

Best regards

Gozu09

Comment: I think the problem is your `STATIC_ROOT = ("/home/user/Django/mysite/static"),` you reference a path on your local computer but what you pushed online with git is probably just `mysite/static` or just `static`. Try to change that path to one of the suggestion and see if it works

Comment: Didn't work either :/ I don't understand what you mean by "What you pushed online with git" I didn't used git at any moment, is it needed ? I used the command python3 manage.py collectstatic but that's all ...